# Yii Framework 1 - Import

Tags: php, yii, import, include-path

I have the two files like this **extras/file1.php** and **extras/file2.test.php**

When i use Yii Import

`Yii::import('application.extras.file1')` ->this way works.

`Yii::import('application.extras.file2.test')` ->In this way, how can i tell Yii that *file2.test* is a file, not *file2/test*.

Thanks !

Comment: What about directory inclusion. I.e. `extras.*`

Comment: Can you tell me more detail ?

Comment: you can use Yii::import('application.extars.*') and then you can use any file  which under extras folder. hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

**Yii::import()**
Imports a class or a directory.

Note : Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable. It will not import .test file.

If you want to import file, you can use

```
Yii::import('application.extras.file1');
```

If you want to import directory, you can use

```
Yii::import('application.extras.*');
```

Ref1 :http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase/#import-detail